# mvc problem in nginx

Tags: model-view-controller, nginx, url-routing, url-rewriting

hello im trying to make somekind of mvc, well at least for learning propose,

example,

```
/application/test.php
/views
/model
index.php
```

when i go to

```
www.mvc.com/test.php
```

it will go strait to `test.php`

is there a way to do things like this ? 
maybe useing htacsess ? if im in a nginx ( im new to `nginx` ) is there some kind of htacsess so i can get the url then redirect ( like `router.php` does ? )

thank you for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: MVC as in Model - View - Controller? If so, you are missing the controller part of your development. You would make index.php point to your master controller.php which would then point to the right file based on the variables passed it it. If I'm close, let me know and I'll provide an example for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/application;
    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /test.php last;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```